# custom fetch core data (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, datamodel

**My Data Model**

[image]

**Fetch func**

```
func fetchAndSetResults2(){
    let dataController = DataController.sharedController
    let moc = dataController.managedObjectContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Cart")
    let formatSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "cartId", ascending: true)
    request.sortDescriptors = [formatSort] //[formatSort, nameSort]
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "cartToUser.userId = %@", serverUserId)


    fetchedResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: "cartId", cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultController.delegate = self

    do {
        try fetchedResultController.performFetch()  
    }
    catch {
        fatalError("Error in fetching records")
    }
}
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

**Update: number of row**

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if let sections = fetchedResultController.sections {
        return sections.count
    }
    return 0
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let sections = fetchedResultController.sections {
        let currentSection = sections[section]
        return currentSection.numberOfObjects
    }
    return 0
}
```

I'm new in core data. I'm already fetch data from cart entity. My table view's looks like the screenshot. Look at Cart-user(38)-363690, it shows 2 cell in 1 cart Id because it has 2 photos. how to only show one cell even if it has 2 or more photos?

Comment: Issue may be with the numberofsections and numberofrowsinsection methods. Please add that methods here

Comment: ok, please check my edited question @Johnykutty

Comment: Cart-user(38)-XXXXX is part of table view cell or its section title?

Comment: I think it is section title, so for you, if photos is there it should show only one row and display the count of photos there correct?

Comment: section, actually i use section only to show how much cell in 1 cart id. i want to only show 1 cell for each cartId. @Johnykutty

Comment: @Johnykutty the cell count as much as photos in cartId, should i provide my insert function to core data?

Comment: Try the answer and see

Answer (score 0):

From this what I can Understand is  if photos is there for cart it should show only one row and display the count of photos in the cell. For that the `numberOfRowsInSection` method should return only 1. No need to return number of images. and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method configure the row based on number of photos in the section.

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
     if let sections = fetchedResultController.sections {
        return sections.count
     }
     return 0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
     let title: String
     if let sections = fetchedResultController.sections {
        let currentSection = sections[indexPath.section]
        title  = "\(currentSection.numberOfObjects) Photos"
     } 
     else {
        title  = "0 Photos"
     }
     //set the label title for photos

    return cell
}
```

Comment: hey thank you for the answer. it works but is there any way to do this without change the section? i mean i use section only to guide me and planned to hide sectionTile later.

Comment: I couldn't get full context of your need.So this is method I an assure based on my understanding